# Transaction Processor gossip in Hyperledger Sawtooth distibuted mode

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

AFAIK, in Hyperledger Sawtooth I can add custom Transaction Processors, but I don't clearly understand can I add them dynamically, and how it will work?

For example, I have working validators network with dynamic peering and want to add new custom Transaction Processor to support new transaction family. Probably, I can run docker container with TP on some machines of network, but often I will not able to do that *on all* machines (which can be closed to me in production).

Thanks advance

Comment: One way is to substitute a service in a compose by overriding it when you compose up. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/ for options and alternatives.

Comment: Franc, thanks for your attention and response. I think this way is good for local deployment with docker-compose, but in 'production' environment (or close to it) I woud like to use 'ubuntu service' way of node deploy and probably I will not have access to all machines after cluster installation, so this question is still interesting for me.

Comment: Are you running hyperledger/sawtooth native or vis-a-vis docker on the ubuntu targets?

Comment: Franc, I'm experementing with https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/app_developers_guide/ubuntu.html tutorial (node as linux service) and planning to use this mode in project

Comment: That is discussing running sawtooth outside of docker. In this case if you can get your TP package on the target machine you can run it like any other program.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear. The thing that I still don't understand - if I have large public network - do I need to send this program (TP) on every machine of network?

Comment: Yes, that is how the distributed ledger fault tolerance works. If you lose a node then the other node(s) would process the transaction and for that you need to have your TP's on the active node.

Answer (score 0):

You run the Identity TP just like any other Sawtooth Transaction Processor, on the command line.  After installing package python3-sawtooth-identity, thpe something like this on the command line:

```
/usr/bin/identity-tp -v -C tcp://localhost:4004
```

You can also automate it as a service.